# Build docker image locally in GitHub Actions using docker/build-push-action

Tags: docker, github-actions

I have several Dockerfiles in my project. One is for building `basic` image, which contains some business-level abstractions. Others are building services, based on the `basic` image.

So in my services' Dockerfiles I have something like

```
FROM my-project/base
# Adding some custom logic around basic stuff
```

I am using GitHub Actions as my CI/CD tool.
At first I had a step to install docker into my workers, and then ran something like:

```
- name: Build base image
  working-directory: business
  run: docker build -t my-project/base .

- name: Build and push service
  working-directory: service
  run: |
    docker build -t my-ecr-repo/service .
    docker push my-ecr-repo/service
```

But then I've found docker/build-push-action and decided to use it in my pipeline:

```
- name: Build business-layer container
  uses: docker/build-push-action@v2
  with:
    load: true
    tags: my-project/base
    context: business
    file: business/Dockerfile

- name: Build service
  uses: docker/build-push-action@v2
  with:
    push: true
    tags: my-ecr-repo/service
    context: service
    file: service/Dockerfile
```

As for now, the second step tries to download **docker.io**/my-project/base, and obviously cannot do it, because I never push base image:

```
ERROR: pull access denied, repository does not exist or may require authorization: server message: insufficient_scope: authorization failed
```

The question is:
**What is the correct way to build an image, so it is accessible by the following building steps locally?**

PS:
I don't want to push my naked `basic` image anywhere.

Answer (score 13):

What does work is to use a local registry. This has the advantage of supporting multi-platform builds. For that, switch from `load` to `push` with your base image:

```
jobs:
  local-registry:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    services:
      registry:
        image: registry:2
        ports:
          - 5000:5000
    steps:
      - name: Login to DockerHub
        uses: docker/login-action@v1
        with:
          username: ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_USERNAME }}
          password: ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_TOKEN }}
      # qemu should only be needed for multi-platform images
      - name: Set up QEMU
        uses: docker/setup-qemu-action@v2
      - name: Set up Docker Buildx
        uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v1
        with:
          driver-opts: network=host
      - name: Build business-layer container
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v2
        with:
          push: true
          tags: localhost:5000/my-project/base
          context: business
          file: business/Dockerfile
      - name: Build service
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v2
        with:
          push: true
          tags: my-ecr-repo/service
          context: service
          file: service/Dockerfile
          build-args: |
            BASE_IMAGE=localhost:5000/my-project/base
```

I'd pass the base image as a build arg to make it easier for use cases outside of Github actions; your Dockerfile would then allow the base image to be specified as a build arg, and you can still do a local Docker build that drops the `localhost:5000` repository:

```
ARG BASE_IMAGE=my-project/base
FROM ${BASE_IMAGE}
# ...
```

---

At some point in the future, docker will switch to using containerd directly for image storage. That will allow multi-platform images and should make it possible to use buildkit with the local image repository in more situations. You can follow the progress on that in the [docker roadmap](https://github.com/docker/roadmap/issues/371).

Comment: Can we use cache-from and cache-to in this case? I guess we need to use `with: driver-opts: network=host' to access images, right ?

Comment: @semural `cache-from` and `cache-to` should work with `load`. If you are having issues with that, please open a separate question with a [mcve].

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is it possible to push images to registry as well using local-registry?

Comment: @semural I haven't tested that. If you have issues with it then open that as a new question.

Answer (score 9):

The github action `docker/setup-buildx-action@v1` defaults to driver `docker-container` [as documented](https://github.com/docker/setup-buildx-action#customizing).
This means builds will run, by default, in a container and thus images won't be available outside of the action.
The solution is to set the driver to `docker`:

```
     ...

      - name: Set up Docker Buildx
        uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v1
        with:
          driver: docker # defaults to "docker-containerized"

      - name: Build business-layer container
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v2
        with:
          # using "load: true" forces the docker driver
          # not necessary here, because we set it before
          #load: true
          tags: my-project/base:latest
          context: business
          file: business/Dockerfile

      - name: Build service
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v2
        with:
          # using "push: true" will lead to error:
          # Error: buildx call failed with: auto-push is currently not implemented for docker driver
          # so you will have to follow the solution outlined here:
          # https://github.com/docker/build-push-action/issues/100#issuecomment-715352826
          # and push the image manually following the build
          #push: true
          tags: my-ecr-repo/service:latest
          context: service
          file: service/Dockerfile

      # list all images, you will see my-ecr-repo/service and my-project/base
      - name: Look up images
        run: docker image ls

      # push the image manually, see above comment
      - name: Push image
        run: docker push my-ecr-repo/service:latest

     ...
```

Comment: this doesnt work if you want to use cache-from/cache-to

Answer (score 1):

For whatever reason, using `load: true` did not work for me when using `build-push-action` (it should just be needed on the first one, but tried adding them on both too). And I needed to use `cache-from` and `cache-to` for my first build so I could not change from the default "docker-container" driver.

What ended up working for me was to use the action only for the first build and do the second one with a `run` command.

Something like:

```
- name: Build business-layer container
  uses: docker/build-push-action@v2
  with:
    load: true
    tags: my-project/base
    context: business
    file: business/Dockerfile

- name: Build service
  run:
    docker build \
      --file service/Dockerfile \
      --tag my-ecr-repo/service \
      service

- name: push service
  run: |
    docker push my-ecr-repo/service
```

Comment: Is it related to [`docker/build-push-action` issue 998](https://github.com/docker/build-push-action/issues/998)?